# Saving multiple checkboxes data into database laravel

Tags: php, laravel, save

Hi guys I need some help saving multiple checkbox into the database. I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work. I am not really sure how to put it correctly but this is how I do it, can someone correct me on how to do it correctly? Thanks in advance.

This is my code: (currently getting this error: `Array to string conversion` pointing to this part at the else, `$id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);`)

```
 if(count($request->input('Pending_Remarks1')|| $request->input('Pending_Remarks2') || $request->input('Pending_Remarks3')) >1){
       $Evaluation['Pending_Remarks1'] = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks1);
       $Evaluation['Pending_Remarks2'] = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks2);
       $Evaluation['Pending_Remarks3'] = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks3);
       $id = $request->user_id;
        $id= PersonalInfo::find($id);
        $id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);
   }else{

        $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks1 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks1');
        $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks2 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks2');
        $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks3 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks3');
         $id = $request->user_id;
        $id= PersonalInfo::find($id);
        $id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);
   }
```

In the past, I did something like this and it work, but when I try to do it for pending remark codes, it doesn't work.

```
 if(count($request->input('Driver_license_class'))>1){
       $testa['Driver_license_class'] = implode(' , ', $request->Driver_license_class);
       $object->update($testa);
   }else{

        $object->Driver_license_class = $request->input('Driver_license_class');
        $object->update();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error you are getting is the first `$id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);)`, I believe you need set the property of that object rather than setting the array. Looks like Laravel can't save the data because its a standard array.

```
 if(count($request->input('Pending_Remarks1')|| $request->input('Pending_Remarks2') || $request->input('Pending_Remarks3')) >1){
   $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks1 = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks1);
   $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks2 = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks2);
   $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks3 = implode(' , ', $request->Pending_Remarks3);

}else{

    $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks1 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks1');
    $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks2 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks2');
    $Evaluation->Pending_Remarks3 = $request->input('Pending_Remarks3');

}

if(isset($request->user_id)){ 
     $id = $request->user_id;
     $id= PersonalInfo::find($id);
     $id->evaluations()->save($Evaluation);
}
```

Comment: sorry for not saying it clear, I forgotten there are 2 similar part in the question, the error is actually pointing at the else part not the if part so does your answer still need to be changed?

Comment: ahh so you're having trouble saving when there are no checkboxes checked? If so, it makes sense that its working in the "if" portion because you're saving those as strings rather than the direct $_GET['Pending_Remarks'] which probably contains an empty array.

Comment: Yup, I have no idea why but in my old code I tried it works but now I don't know where am i going wrong, I have already put nullable inside my database so I am able to still submit if it is empty

Comment: You should dd `$request->input('Pending_Remarks1'`and make sure its a string.

Comment: It gave me an array based on my question, does that mean i have to do an implode on the else statement as well?

Comment: I just want to make something like if the user leave the checkbox empty, other data will still be save but if the user check the checkbox, other data will also be saved together

Comment: Correct! You can't save the array to the database. You may just need to do a for each or implode. Let me know if that works!

Comment: @DavideLapham I tried doing something like if and elseif where each of them just do an implode of the specific remark and after that inside the else i remove everything and only put the saving part and everything works

Comment: Nice! Yeah I thought about that. You were wrapping all of those in one `if` with the `||`.